# How to give path of opencv during creating a jar file from command promt

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

I am creating a jar file from command prompt in windows using   "java -jar cfvm crop.jar Manifest.mf Crop.class"  I am using opencv_300.jar in my project. 
I have also compiled and build my project in netbeans and configured the opencv path in Vvmoptions of project properties. it is successfully running in netbeans. but not working in jar file created in dist folder of project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to link path to dynamic libraries or .dll file when creating a jar file or compiling it in command prompt. OpenCV in java is used as a dynamic library and needs to be linked at runtime. In IDEs its has an vm option to give path for these dll files or it should be placed java.library.path.

To link these .dll files, first compile your project and then run with following command

```
java -Djava.library.path=c:\path_to_dll_file YourApp
```